# web view not loaded correctly on tab

Tags: android, html, webview

i have this web view that i'm loading it from a web service,every phone i installed the app on (all of them are kitkat and above) it was looking great and formatted (having bold titles). but i installed the app on an old tablet having ice cream sandwich software and the text wasn't as other phones the bold tags were not loaded. can you help
here's my code:

```
 if (MyApplication.lang.equals("en")) {
        userGuide.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", "<html><head>\n" +
                "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;\"/>" +
                "<style type=\"text/css\">\n" +
                "@font-face {\n" +
                "    font-family: MyFont;\n" +
                "    src: url(\"file:///android_asset/OpenSans-Regular.ttf\")\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "body {\n" +
                "    font-family: MyFont;\n" +
                "    font-size: 15;\n" +
                "    text-align: justify;\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "</style><body>" + MyApplication.contact.getDataEn() + "</body></html>", "text/html", "UTF-8", "");

    } else {
        userGuide.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", "<html><head>\n" +
                "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;\"/>" +
                "<style type=\"text/css\">\n" +
                "@font-face {\n" +
                "    font-family: MyFont;\n" +
                "    src: url(\"file:///android_asset/GE_Dinar_Two_Medium.otf\")\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "body {\n" +
                "    font-family: MyFont;\n" +
                "    font-size: 30;\n" +
                "    text-align: justify;\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "</style><body>" + MyApplication.contact.getDataAr() + "</body></html>", "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
    }
    userGuide.setBackgroundColor(0);
```

[image: on nexus]

[image: on tablet]

Comment: Long shot here: Are you sure it is Jelly Bean and above? If it's Kit Kat and above, it could be because Google changed the WebView completely. https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html If it is Jelly Bean, not sure of the reason, but it looks something is going on with your CSS rules. Are they in inline style attributes in the body you retrieve using MyApplication.contact.getData*()? Because I cannot see it in the code you attached.

Comment: sorry, kitkat and above, and yeah the styling is received from the service

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, given the [complete change that WebView had in KitKat](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html), I'll suggest using Chrome Developer Tools to check what's the problem. Steps:

1. Connect your device to your computer using USB cable
2. Make sure [developer options are enabled](http://www.greenbot.com/article/2457986/how-to-enable-developer-options-on-your-android-phone-or-tablet.html) in the settings
3. Open Google Chrome and navigate to chrome://inspect
4. From there, you will be able to select your WebView and remotely inspect it, make adjustments, etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @eshteghel-company did my answer helped you?